How to modify a template pptx via python
I have a powerpoint presentation with 10 slides in it that I use as a template.
I want to modify  6 background pictures from the 6th slide in it by replacing them with 6 other picutres from a file using python, considering that this slide contains 9 pictures(where 6 are in the background) 2 placeholders 9 textboxes 6 autoshape 2 lines
The point is to ask the user  the file path and then the code will modify the 5th slide with the pictures in the called file , every picture will be placed specifically in the slide by their name
The places for each new pictures are specific in the slide according to their name so I tried to use index of the old pictures to modify and replace them in the right place.
My problem is that ,even though I checked million times the indexes of each old pictures I want to modify to ensure they will be replaced correctly, the new ones are not in the right place. Sometimes some replace the text box, some don't just appear.
Here below is the code I've used:
def replace_images_in_slide(prs, slide_index, source_folder, num_images):
    slide = prs.slides[slide_index]
    image_shapes = [shape for shape in slide.shapes if shape.shape_type == 13]  # 13 est l'index pour les images
    if len(image_shapes) < num_images + 1:
        print(f"Il doit y avoir au moins {num_images + 1} images sur la diapositive. Seulement {len(image_shapes)} trouvées.")
        return
    image_files = [f for f in os.listdir(source_folder) if f.endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif'))][:num_images]
    if len(image_files) < num_images:
        print(f"Il doit y avoir au moins {num_images} images dans le dossier. Seulement {len(image_files)} trouvées.")
        return
    for i in range(num_images):
        image_shape = image_shapes[i+1]
        left, top, width, height = image_shape.left, image_shape.top, image_shape.width, image_shape.height
        sp = image_shape._element
        sp.getparent().remove(sp)
        image_path = os.path.join(source_folder, image_files[i])
        slide.shapes.add_picture(image_path, left, top, width, height)

pptx_file = "sec1 avec contraintes.pptx" if contrainte == "Y" else "sec1 sans contraintes.pptx"
output_pptx = "sec1 contraintes MODIF.pptx" if contrainte == "Y" else "sec1 sans contraintes MODIF.pptx"
source_folder = "6 images" if contrainte == "Y" else "3 images"


replace_images_in_slide(prs, 5, source_folder, 6 if contrainte == "Y" else 3)


what is "prs"? in any case, i would try and simplify the issue. first start with 6 slides containing just the background images, then keep adding stuff until something breaks.
